# get elements from json

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.4

I want to have a java list for all elements which are in the "in" or "out" element.

My json string:

```
{"in":[
       {"id":4,"ip":"192.168.0.20","pinSysNo":4,"pinSysName":"pg6","folderName":"gpio4_pg6","alias":"d","direction":"digital_in"},
       {"id":3,"ip":"192.168.0.20","pinSysNo":3,"pinSysName":"pb18","folderName":"gpio3_pb18","alias":"c","direction":"digital_out"}
      ],
 "out":[
       {"id":1,"ip":"192.168.0.20","pinSysNo":1,"pinSysName":"pg3","folderName":"gpio1_pg3","alias":"a","direction":"digital_in"},
       {"id":2,"ip":"192.168.0.20","pinSysNo":2,"pinSysName":"pb16","folderName":"gpio2_pb16","alias":"b","direction":"digital_in"}
            ]
}:""
```

Until now I did this way:

```
String message = json.findPath("in").textValue();
```

But this way can only access to the first hierarchy.

My json example show two elements in the "in" element. How I can get a list of these internal "in" elements?

Comment: Which library do you use to parse the json doc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I found an other way to find all sub elements.
Json example:

```
{"in":[
            {"id":4,"ip":"192.168.0.20","pinSysNo":4,"pinSysName":"pg6","folderName":"gpio4_pg6","alias":"d","direction":"digital_in"},
            {"id":3,"ip":"192.168.0.20","pinSysNo":3,"pinSysName":"pb18","folderName":"gpio3_pb18","alias":"c","direction":"digital_out"}
            ],
      "out":[
            {"id":1,"ip":"192.168.0.20","pinSysNo":1,"pinSysName":"pg3","folderName":"gpio1_pg3","alias":"a","direction":"digital_in"}
            ,{"id":2,"ip":"192.168.0.20","pinSysNo":2,"pinSysName":"pb16","folderName":"gpio2_pb16","alias":"b","direction":"digital_in"}
            ]
}
```

My solution:

```
JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
Logger.info("JSON : " + json.findPath("in").findPath("id"));
Logger.info("JSON : " + json.findValues("in"));
List<JsonNode> ins = new org.json.simple.JSONArray();
ins = json.findValues("in");

for (final JsonNode objNode : ins) {

    for (final JsonNode element : objNode) {
        Logger.info(">>>>>" + element.findPath("id"));
        //create my object for database
    }
}
```

Now I can create my Object for the database.
@eztam thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use the library [JSONSimple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/) in order to parse your JSON data by this code:

```
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject o = (JSONObject) parser.parse(yourJsonAsString);
    JSONArray ins = (JSONArray) o.get("in");
    JSONArray outs = (JSONArray) o.get("out");

    String firstIpAddress = ((JSONObject) ins.get(0)).get("ip").toString();
```

Comment: Do you mean like that : JSONObject o = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json.asText()); I get an ecxeption : org.json.simple.parser.ParsException. This is my Json Object : JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();

Comment: I executed the code from above with the JSON you've posted in the question and it worked very well. I guess, that your JSON is not in a proper format. What does `json.asText()` exactly return? Is it valid JSON ?